# Get users which have orders in one row but doesn't have in another SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have one table shown in the image below. I need to get all users which have an order in February but don't have an order in March.

I have the following query but I don't have an idea how to finish it.

```
SELECT *
FROM My_Table
WHERE Order > 0
    AND Date BETWEEN '20150201' AND '20150228' 

User       Date         order
-----------------------------
Aleks     2015-02-01    100
Tatya     2015-03-10    200
Sabine    2015-02-08    300
Aleks     2015-03-27    150
```

Comment: SELECT * is misleading when you write you need users. Is that because you want all rows that is between '20150201' AND '20150228' ?

Comment: No picture showing the table structure..... please post the table structure **as text** (as SQL statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `not exists` with the correlated subquery:

```
select * 
from [My_Table] t
where [Order] > 0
  and ([Date] between '20150201' and '20150228')
  and not exists ( select *
                   from [My_Table]
                   where [Order] > 0
                     and [User] = t.[User]
                     and [Date] between '20150301' and '20150331')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want each user once:

```
SELECT User
FROM My_Table
WHERE
  Order > 0
  AND Date BETWEEN '20150201' AND '20150331' 
GROUP BY User
HAVING max(date) < '20150301'
```

Comment: I need that aleks which has order in both monts do not show up here

Comment: I made a cut and paste typo which has been corrected now